# Let $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ be three points on a circle $|t|=1$. If $x_1,x_2,x_2$ are the arguments of the numbers...[CONT]

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ be three points on a circle $|t|=1$. If $x_1,x_2,x_2$ are the arguments of the numbers, find $\cos (x_1-x_2)+\cos (x_2-x_3)+\cos (x_3-x_1)$

I have the solution for this question, but I am having trouble understand it. It’s written as

$$|t_1|=|t_2|=|t_3|=1$$

So 
$$|t_1+t_2+t_3|^2\ge0$$

$$|t_1|^2+|t_2|^2+|t_3|^2+2Re(z_1\bar z_1+z_2\bar z_2+z_3\bar z_3)\ge 0$$

$$3+2(\cos (x_1-x_2)+\cos  (x_2-x_3)+\cos (x_3-x_1))\ge 0$$

$$\cos (x_1-x_2)+\cos (x_2-x_3)+\cos (x_3-x_1)\ge \frac{-3}{2}$$

My question is, what is the explanation behind the first expansion of $|t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^3|$?

**Note: I think $z$ is supposed to be $t$. It might be a mistake, but I wasn’t sure so I typed it out as it was.**

Comment: Yes, $z$ should be $t$, and the indices are also in error. Another issue with this is that it says to find the sum of the cosines, whereas your "solution" just proves an inequality about the sum. That does not qualify as "finding" it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair what’s wrong with the indices?

Comment: Compare the indices of the $z$ terms in what you wrote to the corresponding terms in my answer and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complex number $z, |z|^2 = z\bar z$. So
$$\begin{align}|t_1+t_2+t_3|^2 &= (t_1+t_2+t_3)(\bar t_1+\bar t_2+\bar t_3)\\
&= t_1\bar t_1 + t_2\bar t_2+t_3\bar t_3 + (t_1\bar t_2 + t_2\bar t_1) + (t_2\bar t_3 + t_3\bar t_2) + (t_3\bar t_1 + t_1\bar t_3)\\
&=|t_1|^2 + |t_2|^2 +|t_3|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}(t_1\bar t_2)+ 2\operatorname{Re}(t_2\bar t_3)+ 2\operatorname{Re}(t_3\bar t_1)\\
&= 1 + 1 + 1 +2\left(\cos(x_1 - x_2) + \cos(x_2 - x_3) + \cos(x_3 - x_1)\right)
\end{align}$$

Note that $t_1 + t_2 + t_3 = 0$ when the points are equally spaced. I.e. have angles of $\frac {2\pi}3$ between them, so this minimum is obtainable.